# Which version of Android supports File Input Streaming?

Tags: android, media-player

I need to know if android version 2.1 , 2.2 or 2.3 support `online radio streaming`, if not could you please tell me which one supports?

Comment: I think your question should be "Which version of Android supports File Input Streaming?" and the answer would be "as low as 1.5 (Cupcake)"

Comment: Ok john please tell which version supports....i am trying with 2.2 not at all streaming.....

Comment: Perhaps more detail would harvest more responses and better scoring.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, streaming audio is possible with all mentioned versions. One of the simpler examples I've seen can be found here http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/

This example shows the usage of `android.media.MediaPlayer` with a HTTP protocol URL.